# set min date time picker to 100 years ago only, visual basic 2012

Tags: vb.net, date, datetimepicker

Its a fairly simple problem but I have been at this for the last 8 hours on other things, and now it all crumbles unless I can set the date time picker minimun to 100 years ago and no more. I can set the max to the current date but setting the minimun I can't. I mean I could do it manually if push comes to it, but I'd rather have an elegant solution.

My code:

```
  'this works flawlessly 
  DTP_DOB.MaxDate = DateTime.Now
  'this I just can't make it work.
  DTP_DOB.MinDate =
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative value in the [AddYears method of DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx).

```
DTP_DOB.MaxDate = DateTime.Now
' Probably want to use a constant or a variable (config?)
DTP_DOB.MinDate = DTP_DOB.MaxDate.AddYears(-100)
```

Comment: It never even occurred to me to add a negative number there. I feel, very, very dumb. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It the parameter is an "Int", you can always try to use a negative number. If not sure, you can also check the documentation ;). It states: "Parameter `value`: A number of years. The value parameter can be negative or positive. "